# A Scala generic function which can accept any T.Value given T extends Enumeration?

Tags: scala, generics, enums

I'm trying to make some functions which use both the whole Enumeration and single values chosen from an Enumeration as arguments.

It's easy to make a generic function which accepts any kind of Enumeration object as it's argument, but how can I make a generic function which accepts any single value from an Enumeration as it's argument?

```
object Xenu extends Enumeration {
  type Xenu = Value
  val foo, bar, baz = Value
}

object Yenu extends Enumeration {
  type Yenu = Value
  val blip, blop, blap, blep = Value
}


def doStuff[E <: Enumeration](e:E):Int = {
  // Works fine
  println("Got an enum: " + e.toString())
  e.values.size
}

def funnyBusiness[E <: Enumeration](v: E.Value): Unit = {
  // This doesn't work!
  println(v)
}

doStuff(Xenu) // Works
doStuff(Yenu) // Works

funnyBusiness(Xenu.bar) // Wrong
funnyBusiness(Yenu.blip) // Wrong
```

Can you help me write a generic function declaration for "funnyBusiness" such that I can accept any single value from any Enumeration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you will be able to achieve with such a signature, but here you go:

The problem in your `funnyBusiness` is that you use the `.` notation for the type `E`, which does not exists. To use a type-dependant type, you use the `#` notation, such as `E#Value`.

Apart from this, your function is fine:

```
def funnyBusiness[E <: Enumeration](v: E#Value): Unit = {
  println(v)
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but this is a greatly simplified version of a function which actually does something useful. You correctly found the answer. Green tick +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

And the solution turns out to be very easy:

```
def funnyBusiness[E <: Enumeration](v: E#Value): Unit = {
  // This doesn't work!
  println(v)
}
```